# Session value not set Properly in Logged users Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, session, values, id

In my mobile number update module, logged user **userId** and **mobilenumber** set to .phtml hidden fields, but some times its not works properly !  please check my code

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Block/Account/Dashboard/Updatemobile.php

```
<?php
namespace {vendor}\{module}\Block\Account\Dashboard;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Updatemobile extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customersession;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customersession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerid()
    {
        $customerId = 0;
        if ($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerId = $this->_customersession->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
        return $customerId;
    }

    public function getMobilenumber()
    {
        $mobileNumber = 0;
        if ($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $mobileNumber = $this->_customersession->getCustomer()->getMobilenumber();
        }
        return $mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/templates/updateMobile.phtml

```
<div class="update_mob">
    <div class="update_mob_text">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $block->getMobilenumber(); ?>" class="updatemobnumber"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl("mobilelogin/index/updatemobilenumber"); ?>" class="url" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getCustomerid();?>" class="userId" />
        <span><?php echo __("You will get all the sms on this number"); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="update_mob_btn">
        <input type="button" value="Update Mobile Number" class="updatemobbtn action primary"/>
         <img class="sms-request-load" src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>" alt="Please Wait..." id="updatemobile_img"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Controller/Index/Updatemobilenumber.php

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{module}\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer as CustomerData;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer as CustomerResource;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory as CustomerResourceFactory;

class Updatemobilenumber extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerData;
    protected $customer;
    protected $customerResourceFactory;
    protected $customerResource;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        Customer $customer,
        CustomerData $customerData,
        CustomerResource $customerResource,
        CustomerResourceFactory $customerResourceFactory,
         $data = array()
        )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->customerData = $customerData;
        $this->customerResourceFactory = $customerResourceFactory;
        $this->customerResource = $customerResource;

    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $mobile = (string)$this->getRequest()->get('mobile');
        $customerId = (string)$this->getRequest()->get('userId');
        $this->customerData = $this->customer->getDataModel();
        $this->customerData->setId($customerId);
        $this->customerData->setCustomAttribute('mobilenumber', $mobile);
        $this->customer->updateData($this->customerData);
        $this->customerResource = $this->customerResourceFactory->create();
        if ($mobile != "") {
            $this->customerResource->saveAttribute($this->customer, 'mobilenumber');
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess("Mobile Number Update successfully");

        $data = 1;     
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data);
        return $resultJson;

    }
}
```

Comment: try removing `$mobileNumber = 0;` and `$customerId = 0;`

Comment: Can you please upload code of your updatemobilenumber controller?

Comment: try `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` instead of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` I have Done same thing Yesterday

Comment: @ Rohan Hapani please check updated Question

Comment: It seems like your first hidden field value always display 1.

Comment: actually both user_id and mobilenumber hidden values display 0

Comment: what is the purpose of use of `$data = 1;` in controller?

Comment: @KKR *$data = 1;* this is for ajax response to identify mobile number update successfully

Comment: @ShafeelSha please remove `$mobileNumber = 0;` and `$customerId = 0;` from your Block file and then please check `$this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()` function is returns proper value or not.

Comment: First of all, check value in DB table that value updated in mobile number attribute or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You're returning the value of `$customerId` and `$mobileNumber`
>   outside of

```
if ($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()) {}
```

**that's why it's returning value `0` since you're initializing with `0` . Update this code in**

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Block/Account/Dashboard/Updatemobile.php

```
    public function getCustomerid()
    {
        if ($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()) {
             return $this->_customersession->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getMobilenumber()
    {
        if ($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn()) {
             return $this->_customersession->getCustomer()->getMobilenumber();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The issue is in $_customersession property

> Underscore isn't needed in your **$_customersession** property you can
>   also try to define property without underscore, it's not needed.

**Change it to**

> $customerSession

**from**

> $_customersession

If you are facing the `cache` issue, you can use in your layout file

> cacheable="false";

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: hi @Mohit Rane , thank you for your response , but  its did not works for me i think my logged session values not correctly fetch

Comment: can you print this `$this->getRequest()->getParams();` Or `$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();` see what it prints

Comment: where ? i keep this code

Comment: in your controller `Updatemobilenumber.php` file

Comment: /index/updatemobilenumber/?mobile=123456798&userId=0&_=1563526335045 500 (Internal Server Error) it shows when i click update mobile number

Comment: you're not adding `name` attribute in hidden field in .phtml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96375/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-mohit-rane).

Comment: @ShafeelSha I've updated an answer. Please accept the answer if it's solved your issue :)